# Integrating uiautomator test cases with Instrumentation test cases

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

We have already written test cases in Android Instrumentation with `InstrumentationTestRunner` now as this does not support app switching so we have planned to create some `UIAutomation` based test cases but we are struggling in merging this test cases. We want to create a single suite from where we can run `Instrumentation` as well as `UiAutomator` test cases.

As far as I know for running UiAutomator requires `AndroidJUnitRunner` but this does not support Instrumentation test cases.

Answer (score 0):

UiAutomator does not require AndroidJUnitRunner, you can use InstrumentationTestRunner if you like.

AndroidJUnitRunner can also run regular Android instrumentation tests, so you could use AndroidJUnitRunner for both types of tests instead.

In general, I'd recommend using AndroidJUnitRunner since it is updated more frequently and supports JUnit4.